# Is it bad to set glTexParameteri() during render time?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am facing issues with texture wrapping. which is causing artifacts. Since my codebase has grown huge the only way that I can think of is to perform certain checks to see if certain textures fall under the category which are causing artifacts and change the parameters before drawing onto the renderbuffer.

So is it generally ok? to set parameters like

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
```

after glBindTexture during render loop? or would it effect FPS as it would increase operations during each render frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing texture parameters usually doesn't have a too serious impact on performance, as it leaves caches intact and only changes the access pattern.

However in later versions of OpenGL for this very specific usage scenario "Sampler Objects" have been introduced. I think you might want to have a look at them.

Comment: I found [Arcsynthesis chapter 14](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tutorial%2014.html) on textures/sampling helpful in regard to this.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule of thumb is this: do not change any state you don't have to.

If a texture has an intrinsic property that makes you use a mirrored-repeat wrapping mode, then it should *always* have that property. Therefore, the texture should have been originally set with that wrapping mode.

If it's something that you *need* to do at render time, then yes, you can do it. Whether it affects your performance adversely depends entirely on how CPU bound your rendering code is.

Note:

> Since my codebase has grown huge

This is never a good reason to do *anything*. If you can't figure out a way to make your code do this the right way, then something bad has probably happened within your codebase. And you should fix *that* before trying to deal with this texture issue.

Comment: While I agree, that normally texture sampling parameters are tied to the texture contents, there are a few cases, where a single texture can be sensibly used with different sampling parameters. For example you may have some LUT which may be used either wrapped cyclic, or mirror cyclic, depending on the use. For example the same bands texture may be used in a marble shader (mirrored cycle) and a wood shader (wrapped cycle) with different texcoord generation methods.

Comment: Thank you for all the valid justifications. It totally makes sence now :-)