# How fast is it to change the texture filters in OpenGL at runtime?

Tags: opengl

I'm at this point where I would like to render a texture twice but with different filters.
It seems like a very bad idea to store the texture twice with different filters, that would take up way too much V-RAM. So I came up with the idea to just change the filters on the go, but how fast is it?

I'm thinking of doing it like this:

```
// First render call
BindTexture(...);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
RenderObject( ... );

BindTexture(...);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
RenderObject( ... );
```

So the final question is: How fast is it to update the texture parameters at runtime?

Comment: What is stopping you from testing this yourself?

Comment: Possible dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722107/is-it-bad-to-set-gltexparameteri-during-render-time

Comment: By the way, you probably meant to call `glBindTexture` *before* `glTexParameter`, since the latter works, like any other texture function, on the currently bound texture object.

Comment: Maybe samplers would be a good feature for your use-case, but of course it is to be seen if they really bring a performance improvement in your case (but they should certainly bring a usability and clarity improvement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I came up with the idea to just change the filters on the go, but how fast is it?

To the GPU it's merely a single register which value changes. So it's quite cheap. But the way you wrote it doesn't make much sense.

Since filtering parameters are part of the texture object, you set them *after* `glBindTexture` of the texture object in question.

If you want to use just the same texture with different filtering parameters you don't have to re-bind it inbetween.

Also since OpenGL-3.3 there's a class of data-less object (data-less objects can't be shared) called samplers. Samplers collect texture sampling parameters (like filtering), while textures provide the data. So if you want to switch filteing parameters often, or you have a common mode of sampling parameters for a large set of texture you can do this using a single sampler serving multiple textures.

See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object

Comment: I think samplers are core since 3.3, though. And I took the freedom of adjusting your link, it was referring to the GLSL type and not the API type.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, you're right about them being part of OpenGL-3.3 core. I just never used them before also using OpenGL-4, hence that.

Comment: it's also worth noting that the cost of a syscall is nontrivial if you want to be doing it several times every render.

Comment: @bfops: Syscalls are the least of your problems there. For one most in most systems the OpenGL implementation is loaded into the address space of the process so there's not context switch when doing OpenGL calls. And then on modern systems syscalls are not expensive either. The cost of OpenGL state changes are caused by the requirement, that the GPU must follow those state changes in the order they come in, when actually processing the whole rendering patch (which may happen late after the actual calls are made). Some changes bring the pipeline down to a full stop and hence should be avoided.

Comment: Oh cool good to know. Now that you say it, it makes sense that the cost of serialization would be the biggest penalty you pay. Thanks!

Comment: @bfops: It's not so much the serialization (by which I understand the process of writing out commands and data into a *serial* stream) but the *enforced* order of execution of commands on the GPU. If I tell the GPU to draw quad_1+texture_1 → quad_2+texture_2 → quad_3+texture_1 the drawing operations must happen in *exactly* that order for things like blending and depth testing to work; some GPU architectures internally reorder the operations in a that an effectively identical result is produced. However the less expensive state changes the easier it gets for the GPU.

Comment: oops, right idea, wrong terminology. Realizing now that serialization isn't the same as "making things serial" (by which I meant the steps in the computation). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This depends highly on the implementation of GL you are using.  Like anything performance-related, just test and see if it's fast enough for your specific application on your target hardware.

Relatively recent versions of GL include a feature called [Samplers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object) which are object you can create with various texture parameters.  You can create a number of different samplers and then swap these out as needed rather than reconfiguring an existing texture.  This also allows you to use two different texture sampling states for the same texture if necessary.  This *should* be faster in general, but again, just test and see what works best in your specific circumstance.

Comment: I took the freedom of adjusting your link, it was referring to the GLSL type and not the API type.